# How can I view file read/write logs in xcode for debug app

Tags: xcode, debugging, audio, logging

How can I view the file logs for a debug version of an app without actually importing the project into Xcode?  I can do this in Android Studio but I am not sure how to do it in Xcode.  I want to run a debug version of an app and view the generated audio logs for that app. Any help appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by audio logs, but you can see log outputs from any process on the device in Console.app while you have the device connected to a Mac. You should see the phone in the devices list on the left. That will show you all log activity from the device, but you can also filter to just the process you're interested in by right clicking on one of the messages and choosing `Show Process "XYZ"`.

Comment: I'm testing an app that will record audio and then generate audio logs.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yep no problem!